# Stored Procedure values not insert XML node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Equip_SaveTeamTaskAssigineeDetails] (
@saveDataXML xml)
as 
begin

    Declare @claimid int,
            @createdate datetime,
            @duedate datetime,
            @startdate datetime,
            @assignmentid int,
            @assignedto varchar(50),
            @piority varchar(50),
            @comment varchar(4000)



    select  @claimid = node.value('claimid[1]','int'),
            @createdate = node.value('createdate[1]','datetime'),
            @duedate = node.value('duedate[1]','datetime'),
            @startdate = node.value('startdate[1]','datetime'),
            @assignmentid = node.value('assignmentid[1]','int'),
            @assignedto = node.value('assignedto[1]','varchar(50)'),
            @piority= node.value('piority[1]','varchar(50)'),
            @comment = node.value('comment[1]','varchar(4000)')


        from @saveDataXML.nodes('/TeamTaskDetails/Task') nodes(node)  

IF (@claimid = 0)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO  [dbo].[TeamTaskAssiginment]
               ([claimid],
                [createdate],
                [duedate],
                [startdate],
                [assignedid],
                [assiginedto],
                [priority],
                [comment])




               VALUES
                (@claimid,
            @createdate,
            @duedate,
            @startdate ,
            @assignmentid ,
            @assignedto ,
            @piority ,
            @comment
                )

        --SET @claimid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            Update [dbo].[TeamTaskAssiginment] set


            claimid=@claimid ,
                createdate=@createdate,
                duedate=@duedate,
                startdate=@startdate,
                assignedid=@assignedto,
                assiginedto=@assignedto,
                priority=@piority,
                comment=@comment

        END

Execute Stored Procedure 

Exec Equip_SaveTeamTaskAssigineeDetails @saveDataXML =
<TeamTaskDetails>
<Task claimid="1" createdate="2000-12-16" duedate="2000-12-16" startdate="2000-12-16" assignmentid="1" assignedto="test"  piority="HIGH" comment="test"  />
</TeamTaskDetails>
```

If I executed Stored Procedure its showing 0 Rows Affected values not inserting

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: You are assigning the variables incorrectly, to extract the attributes rather than the text use `@`, e.g. `SELECT @claimid = node.value('@claimid[1]','int')`- This means your variables are null. so in the `IF` you go to the update statement. I assume there is no rows in the table, which is why you get `0 rows affected`. Are you sure your query in the  `ELSE` condition is correct? There is no where clause so looks like you would update every record in the table?

Comment: your xml query is wrong, it returns nulls so the insert won't be hit. and your update query has no where clause, which i'm guessing may not be intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You're querying the xml wrong, to get the attribute values you need to query it like so, replacing `claimid[1]`:

```
SELECT  @claimid = node.value('@claimid', 'int') ,....
```

Full sample:

```
DECLARE @saveDataXML AS XML = 
    '<TeamTaskDetails>
        <Task claimid="1" createdate="2000-12-16" duedate="2000-12-16" 
              startdate="2000-12-16" assignmentid="1" assignedto="test"  
              piority="HIGH" comment="test"  />
    </TeamTaskDetails>'

DECLARE @claimid INT ,
    @createdate DATETIME ,
    @duedate DATETIME ,
    @startdate DATETIME ,
    @assignmentid INT ,
    @assignedto VARCHAR(50) ,
    @piority VARCHAR(50) ,
    @comment VARCHAR(4000)



SELECT  @claimid = node.value('@claimid', 'int') ,
        @createdate = node.value('@createdate', 'datetime') ,
        @duedate = node.value('@duedate', 'datetime') ,
        @startdate = node.value('@startdate', 'datetime') ,
        @assignmentid = node.value('@assignmentid', 'int') ,
        @assignedto = node.value('@assignedto', 'varchar(50)') ,
        @piority = node.value('@piority', 'varchar(50)') ,
        @comment = node.value('@comment', 'varchar(4000)')
FROM    @saveDataXML.nodes('/TeamTaskDetails/Task') nodes ( node )  


SELECT  claimid = @claimid ,
        createdate = @createdate ,
        duedate = @duedate ,
        startdate = @startdate ,
        assignedid = @assignedto ,
        assiginedto = @assignedto ,
        priority = @piority ,
        comment = @comment
```

Ouput:

```
claimid createdate  duedate     startdate   assignedid....
1       2000-12-16  2000-12-16  2000-12-16  test...
```

Also, as I commented, the insert isn't hit because your current select is returning nulls, so `IF (@claimid = 0)` won't return true. And your update query will update every row unless you specify a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

There no END for the BEGIN Statement.
Please try this code

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Equip_SaveTeamTaskAssigineeDetails] (
@saveDataXML xml)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @claimid int,
            @createdate datetime,
            @duedate datetime,
            @startdate datetime,
            @assignmentid int,
            @assignedto varchar(50),
            @piority varchar(50),
            @comment varchar(4000)



    select  @claimid = node.value('claimid[1]','int'),
            @createdate = node.value('createdate[1]','datetime'),
            @duedate = node.value('duedate[1]','datetime'),
            @startdate = node.value('startdate[1]','datetime'),
            @assignmentid = node.value('assignmentid[1]','int'),
            @assignedto = node.value('assignedto[1]','varchar(50)'),
            @piority= node.value('piority[1]','varchar(50)'),
            @comment = node.value('comment[1]','varchar(4000)')


        from @saveDataXML.nodes('/TeamTaskDetails/Task') nodes(node)  

    IF (@claimid = 0) BEGIN
        INSERT INTO  [dbo].[TeamTaskAssiginment]
               ([claimid],
                [createdate],
                [duedate],
                [startdate],
                [assignedid],
                [assiginedto],
                [priority],
                [comment])




               VALUES
                (@claimid,
            @createdate,
            @duedate,
            @startdate ,
            @assignmentid ,
            @assignedto ,
            @piority ,
            @comment
                )

        --SET @claimid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
     END ELSE BEGIN
            Update [dbo].[TeamTaskAssiginment] set


            claimid=@claimid ,
                createdate=@createdate,
                duedate=@duedate,
                startdate=@startdate,
                assignedid=@assignedto,
                assiginedto=@assignedto,
                priority=@piority,
                comment=@comment

      END
END


GO
```

Also check the XML code. It should be in a single inverted comma :

```
--  Execute Stored Procedure    
Exec Equip_SaveTeamTaskAssigineeDetails @saveDataXML =
'<TeamTaskDetails>
<Task claimid="1" createdate="2000-12-16" duedate="2000-12-16" startdate="2000-12-16" assignmentid="1" assignedto="test"  piority="HIGH" comment="test"  />
</TeamTaskDetails>'
```

Comment: Hi , no error but no row affected ,its showing (0 row(s) affected) .please help it

Comment: i think you may be assuming that a typo (missed end) in the question is the problem. i simply assumed the OP trimmed it off by mistake, otherwise he wouldn't be able to create / alter it at all

Comment: @SriramNandha have you tried my answer as i don't think this answer will make any difference to your problem?

Comment: Hi its works fine its inserted .i remove the update query its insert values. but i need update query also.

Comment: values are inserting i had remove the update query values means values are inserted i need update query also

Comment: Hi Tanner, its works fine , how to insert multiple values

Comment: execute query single node values only inserting.i need to insert multiple values

Comment: FROM    @saveDataXML.nodes('/TeamTaskDetails') nodes ( node )  if i use its showing illegal character

Comment: when i insert values

Comment: FROM    @saveDataXML.nodes('/TeamTaskDetails') nodes ( node )  
i need this syntax ,but if i insert values means showing XML parsing: line 2, character 2, illegal qualified name character